# How to check if my ISP limits VoIP traffic?

Tags: service, limit

Recent days there is a rumour that some Internet Service Providers in my country limiting the speed of traffic for certain services e.g. Skype, Whatsapp, Viber, etc. Also in reality neither of those services work properly, I can barely call someone.
Is it possible to prove it technically doing some tests or it's just a Hoax and maybe internet itself is heavily loaded?